# Using getUrl() variable in outer/upper class

Tags: java, android, class, methods, webview

```
String url = "http://xxxx.com/login.php?UID=";
String uid = portal.mysharedvars.getString("uid");

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login_personel_activity);
/*if(newurl.toLowerCase().contains("index.php")) {
I want to do somethings here
                                                 }
*/

    WebView siteview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.personel_webview);
    siteview.setWebViewClient(new MywebViewClient());

    final String link = url+uid;
    siteview.loadUrl(link);
}
private class MywebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // do your stuff here
        String newurl = view.getUrl();
        Toast.makeText(login_personel_webview.this, newurl, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                             }
```

as you see above, I've a link variable in my webview activity with onPageFinished public. I would like to use that variable in starred line with an if statement. How could I get used that variable there?

EDIT: ofc the link will not be static as declared at start. Tats just login page. than will be many pages.

Comment: so you want to access the newurl variable inside onCreate() method?

Comment: yes william. Thats correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try do this through callback

```
String url = "http://xxxx.com/login.php?UID=";
String uid = portal.mysharedvars.getString("uid");

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    WebView siteview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.personel_webview);
    siteview.setWebViewClient(new MywebViewClient(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onPageUrl(String url) {
           if (url.toLowerCase().contains("index.php")) {
               //Do what you want here
           }
        }
    }));

    final String link = url+uid;
    siteview.loadUrl(link);
}
private class MywebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    Callback callback;

    public MywebViewClient(Callback callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // do your stuff here
        String newurl = view.getUrl();
        callback.onPageUrl(newurl);
        Toast.makeText(login_personel_webview.this, newurl, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

public interface Callback {
    void onPageUrl(String url);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Dmitry. Works perfect. +1